# Cart item images are not showing in Order summary

Tags: magento2, order-summary, cart-items

Currently, am adding the product programatically while moving from the **Shipping -> Review & Payments** and facing a problem. The added item image is not showing in the Order Summary other than this all information is displayed correctly. Kindly refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I found that Magento 2 is showing the images using

> Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail.js

and the image source is taken from the **window.checkoutConfig**.

The reason for this issue is **window.checkoutConfig** information will be saved at the initial loading of the checkout and the saved data won't get updated until Refreshing the Page. But all other information are get updated correctly because those information are taken from the API **carts/mine/shipping-information**.

I can overcome the issue by including the image information with the same API. But I need to is there any other better solution?

And the same issue happens if am using two browser tabs.

Step 1: In the First tab am on the checkout page.
Step 2: In the Second tab am adding a product to cart.
Step 3: Then from the First tab am moving from **Shipping -> Review & Payments**. The same thing happens here.

I don't know wheater I can report it as Magento bug. Kindly confirm if you are sure that this one a **Magneto bug**. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: python red shoe product image showing in product page ?

Comment: Yes, it's showing. Even here the image is shown once I refresh the page.

Comment: Got solution ? If yes can you please share how you solved?

Comment: Any solution here? If Yes, Could you please post here @AnushStarlit

Comment: Any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Module Checkout Thumbnail](https://github.com/mikedubinsky/magento2-module-checkout-thumbnail) at Github.